# Color Codes Working Differently in Different Parts of the Code

Tags: html, css

Ok, I typed in a color code wrong, and got a color that I don't seem to be able too recreate, even by copy pasting the typo. Specifically it's the color appearing for h1 that I cannot recreate

Here is the relevant coding pertaining to it:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>The Squeegee Imperium Inc.</h1>
</div>
```

```
.jumbotron h1 {
               color: ##3366FF;
} 

<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>The Squeegee Imperium Inc.</h1>
    <div class="contact">
      <p>
        If you have any comments, questions, or suggestions        services    you would like to see offered, would like to book our services, 
        or to receive or make a payment, please contact us through    one     of the following means.
      </p>

      <p>
        <span style="color:#000000">By Phone:</span>
        <a href="tel:1-587-707-4584">
        <span style="color:##3366FF">1-587-707-4584</span></a>
      </p>
      <p>
        <span style="color:#000000">By Email:</span> 
        <a href="mailto:danielbrow@thesqueegeeimperiuminc.ca">
        <span style="color:##3366FF">DanielBrow@TheSqueegeeImperiumInc.ca</span></a>
      </p>
      <p>
        <span style="color:#000000">By Mail:</span> 
        <span style="color:##3366FF">PO Box 42159 Southland Crossing PO T2J 7A6</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

As you can see though, the color code for the second span in each line is the same as the color code for h1.

Here is the site http://www.thesqueegeeimperiuminc.ca/contact.html

I can't for the life of me see why it changes the color of h1 and not the rest, when it's not even valid due to the typo and should change nothing.

Comment: to clarify, I was trying to make the secondary spans the same color as h1

Comment: color codes starts with single # not double hash, check your css

Comment: Why are you using two hashes in your color codes?

Comment: The double hash for <h1> was an accident. It gave an unexpected color. Given that I am noob, I tried copy pasting it to the secondary spans hoping the color from <h1> would then apply to the secondary spans. Essentially all I am trying to do is too get the color that is applying to h1 to apply to the secondary spans. removing the first # will make it all blue.......

Answer (score 1):

You have two `#`signs in front of the color in the style attribute. Get rid of one, like this:

```
<span style="color:#3366FF">PO Box 42159 Southland Crossing PO T2J 7A6</span>
```

It should work then.

Comment: Also, the `h1` has styles from an external source, so it gets styled while the others don't. Without the second `#`, the color becomes a sort of blue. With it, the `h1` becomes grayish and the `span`'s become black

Comment: oh, ok, it's the bootstrap over riding it. I won't be able to transfer the color from h1 to the rest then. Thank you

Comment: I just have a suggestion: if you're going to  use a background image, put the text in a div with a background, preferably a dark background and some opacity.